# why did my extensions in vsc stop working

Tags: visual-studio, sass

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJZlA.jpg)A message popped up saying "Extension host terminated unexpectedly."  I don't know what to do please help. I see that message but my themes extension is the only one that's working

Comment: You are running a VS Code extension with shortened name 'Developer Extension'. As there are many extensions with that name in VS Code it is hard to say which one it is exactly. That extension may have installed a service or server on your system which stopped working. Have a look to the console in VS Code: maybe you will find additonal error messages or warnings from that extensions there. Posting exact name of extension and such additional error messages can help to get help here ;-)

Comment: I figureed it out!! it was just some problem with the sass extension and not vsc extensions.